# bash problem with single quotes expansion

Tags: bash, shell

I got the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# break on error
set -ex

## USAGE: ./open <type> <instance-name>
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
    echo "## USAGE: ${0} <type> <instance-name>"
    echo "type: team or project"
    echo "instance-name: name of the instance to fetch the URL from"
    exit 1
fi

ORGANIZATION="redacted_org"

PROJECT="redacted_project"

TYPE="redacted_type"
if [[ $1 == "team" ]]; then
  TYPE="redacted_type_team"
fi

NAME=$2

BUILD_ID=$(az pipelines build definition list \
  --organization "${ORGANIZATION}" \
  --project "${PROJECT}" \
  --query "\"[? contains(path, '\\\\stacks\\\\${TYPE}\\\\instances\\\\${NAME}') && name=='apply'].{id:id}\"" \
  --output tsv)

echo "https://redacted_org.visualstudio.com/redacted_project/_build?definitionId=${BUILD_ID}"
```

The problem is that the BUILD_ID variable is being executed as (printed by the `set -x`):

```
++ az pipelines build definition list --organization redacted_org --project redacted_project --query '"[? contains(path, \'\''\\stacks\\redacted_type\\instances\\redacted_2\'\'') && name==\'\''apply\'\''].{id:id}"' --output tsv
```

Note the `'"` instead of `"` just after the --query parameter and in the end of it, and the `\'\'` everywhere I have a single quote instead of `'`

I need this BUILD_ID to be executed as follows, this command works fine when typed in the terminal itself:

```
$(az pipelines build definition list --organization "redacted_org" --project "redacted_project" --query "[? contains(path, '\\stacks\\redacted_type\\instances\\redacted_2') && name=='apply'].{id:id}" --output tsv)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong. This is just how `-x` displays the string in a standard, unambiguous way.

Comment: without the `-x` it doesn't work either, if I try remove the `-x` and using echo in the command just to see the output `BUILD_ID=$(echo az pipelines build definition list \
  --organization "${ORGANIZATION}" \
  --project "${PROJECT}" \
  --query "\"[? contains(path, '\\\\stacks\\\\${TYPE}\\\\instances\\\\${NAME}') && name=='apply'].{id:id}\"" \
  --output tsv)`, it does print as it should, but after removing the echo, still doenst work

Comment: Try `query="[? contains(path, '\\stacks\\redacted_type\\instances\\redacted_2') && name=='apply'].{id:id}"`, then `az pipelines ... --query "$query" --output tsk`; I think you are just overescaping some characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stanza:

```
BUILD_ID=$(az pipelines build definition list \
  --organization "${ORGANIZATION}" \
  --project "${PROJECT}" \
  --query "\"[? contains(path, \'\\\\stacks\\\\${TYPE}\\\\instances\\\\${NAME}\') && name==\'apply\'].{id:id}\"" \
  --output tsv)
```

you've used some bizarre quoting.  You want that to be just the way you expect:

```
BUILD_ID=$(az pipelines build definition list \
  --organization "${ORGANIZATION}" \
  --project "${PROJECT}" \
  --query "[? contains(path, '\\stacks\\${TYPE}\\instances\\${NAME}) && name=='apply'].{id:id}" \
  --output tsv)
```